The group $ \langle x,y \mid xy^{2014} x = y x^{2015} \rangle $ is not trivial
I am self-studying free groups and presentations, so this may be a bit of a trivial question, but:

Is the following argument as to why the group $G := \langle x,y \mid xy^{2014} x = y x^{2015} \rangle$ is not trivial, valid?

(It is Exercise 2.E.14 (3) from Clara Löh's 'Geometric Group Theory'.)
Suppose it is trivial. Then the trivial group $\{e\}$ must satisfy $G$'s universal property of generators and relations (Proposition 2.2.18; Ibid.). I'll show the universal property does not hold. Consider the group $\mathbb Z_2$ (cyclic group of order two) and the map $ \varphi\colon \{x,y\} \longrightarrow \mathbb Z_2 $ which sends both $x$ and $y$ to the generator. Then the relation of $G$ is satisfied in $\mathbb Z_2 $:
$$\varphi(x)+2014\cdot\varphi(y) + \varphi(x) = \varphi(y) + 2015\cdot\varphi(x).$$ However, there does not exist a homomorphism $\overline{\varphi} \colon G = \{e\} \longrightarrow \mathbb Z_2$ which satisfies $\overline{\varphi} \circ \pi = \varphi$, since $\overline{\varphi}(e) = 0$ while $\varphi(x) = 1$.
(Here, $\pi\colon \{x,y\} \longrightarrow G$ maps the letters $x$ and $y$ into the group $G$ where extra relations are put on these letters.)
I suppose what we see here is that we need a couple more relations on $x,y$ in order for the group $G$ to become trivial: it at least has to be forced that $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)=e$ in this specific situation. An argument like the one I just gave would not work for the so called 'complicated trivial group'
$$\langle x,y \mid xyx^{-1} = y^2, yxy^{-1} = x^2 \rangle.$$
The relations $$ \varphi(x) + \varphi(y) - \varphi(x) = 2\varphi(y) \quad \text{and} \quad \varphi(y) + \varphi(x) - \varphi(y) = 2\varphi(x) $$ force both $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)$ to be trivial.
I am aware of a similar question (Is the group $\langle x,y \mid xy^n = yx^n \rangle $ trivial?) but I am trying to do it via the universal property here.
Thanks in advance!

this group admits a surjective map to $\mathbb{Z}/2013\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2013\mathbb{Z}$ so it can't be trivial

Yes OP, your proof is fine.

1-relator groups with more than 1 generator are never trivial.

Very good. I think that whenever the exponents add up to an even number you can use this exact argument, and also note that any word that represents the neutral element is of even length. But the answer below is the most general.

Your argument is fine but it's not really necessary to talk about the trivial group satisfying the universal property; that's overcomplicating things (and I say this as a lover of universal properties myself!). The content of your argument is that $G$ is nontrivial because you've produced a surjection from $G$ onto a nontrivial group, namely $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and that's all you have to say. The way you produce this surjection is by finding some elements (not all zero) of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ satisfying the relations defining $G$; this is where you use the universal property.
As Moishe says in the comments it is true more generally that a group $G$ generated by more generators than relations is nontrivial, which lets you see that this group must be nontrivial "at a glance." This is because the abelianization $G_{ab} = G/[G, G]$ must be nontrivial, since it is the quotient of a free abelian group by another free abelian group of lower rank. In this case the abelianization is (written additively)
$$G_{ab} = \langle x, y \mid 2014y + 2x = 2015x + y \rangle$$
and the relation simplifies to $2013(x - y) = 0$, so $G_{ab} \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2013$ (where the two summands are generated by $x$ and $x - y$, for example).

Okay, thank you! So just to be clear, the universal property is still being used, but implicitly in the theorem that a map $\varphi : { x,y } \longrightarrow \mathbb Z_2$ is extendable to a homomorphism $\varphi: G \longrightarrow \mathbb Z_2$ if (and only if) $\varphi(r) = 0$ for all relations $r$ on $G$, right? I'll revisit this once I'm done with Abelianizations

@Neckverse: yes, although a less categorically minded group theorist might say "that's just the definition of a presentation."
